# 301 redirect from default.asp to home URL

Tags: redirect

I am moving a client's static site into WP and her old site was all done with ASP. I have every old page redirecting correctly except for default.asp.

here is the .htaccess code I am using:

```
Redirect 301 /default.asp http://www.artisticimages.biz
```

It redirects to the home URL but I get an error that says it can't redirect properly - cookies not enabled or something like that.

If anyone can shed some light on this please let me know - I really appreciate it!

Comment: This question is not WordPress related as it currently stands, and is better asked on [SeverFault](http://severfault.com).